# Close Directory Listing on Browser

Tags: php, browser, permissions, directory

I want to close one of my directories public access on my PHP server but at the same time same directory should be still accessible, so what I want to do is when user types that directory from browser like `stackoverflow.com/directory` they will see it closed/empty but when they want to access a file under that directory like `stackoverflow.com/directory/file.php` they will be able read and submit form on it. Any ideas how can I do this?

Many thanks

Comment: create an index.php file in there and redirect the browser to the parent folder as `stackoverflow.com/directory` will default to `stackoverflow.com/directory/index.php` leaving access to `stackoverflow.com/directory/file.php` untouched

Answer (score 0):

Another method, using `.htaccess` file in the root

```
Options -Indexes
```

Now if a folder does not have an index.html/php file the server will respond with a 404 file not found error and send people your error page. Rather than a directory listing denied using the previous method.